# Why do I get a "DOM Level 3 Not implemented" error at run-time?

Tags: java, dom, cxf, xmlbeans

I am currently working on the development of an Apache CXF Web Service with XMLBeans binding instead of the default JAXB binding. I am compiling and running the code with Java 1.6.
I get a "DOM Level 3 Not implemented" error at runtime for the following code snippet :

```
ExtType[] extTypeList = p.getExtArray();
        for (ExtType extType : extTypeList) {               
            Node node = extType.getDomNode();
            NodeList objList = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < objList.getLength(); ++i) {
                Node text = (Node) objList.item(i);                 
                if (text.getNodeName() != null
                        && text.getNodeName() == XmlConstant.NODE_NAME) {

                    info.setDuration(text
                            .getTextContent());
                }
            }
        }
```

The exact error displayed in JBoss is as follows :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: DOM Level 3 Not implemented
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.DomImpl._node_getTextContent(DomImpl.java:2516)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$NodeXobj.getTextContent(Xobj.java:2607)
```

From the above error message, it is clear that the getTextContent method is causing the exexception because the DOM level 3 API's are not found at run-time. How do I eliminate this error? I am guessing I'll have to figure out which jar contains the DOM API's and delete all dom related classes from that jar so that the default DOM API's that come along with jdk are used instead. Alternately, is there a way to get the text contents of an xml tag using DOM without relying on the getTextContent method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears as though XMLBeans provides a DOM implementation that is not DOM 3 compliant based on the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: DOM Level 3 Not implemented
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.DomImpl._node_getTextContent(DomImpl.java:2516)
        at org.a

pache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$NodeXobj.getTextContent(Xobj.java:2607)
```

Instead of `getTextContent` you could iterate over all the child nodes and append the value from all nodes of type text.

```
package forum12746038;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        String xml = "<root>Hello <!-- comment -->World</root>";
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList childNodes = element.getChildNodes();
        StringBuilder strBldr = new StringBuilder();
        for(int x=0; x<childNodes.getLength(); x++) {
            Node childNode = childNodes.item(x);
            if(childNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                strBldr.append(childNode.getNodeValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(strBldr.toString());
    }

}
```

---

> I am guessing I'll have to figure out which jar contains the DOM API's
>   and delete all dom related classes from that jar so that the default
>   DOM API's that come along with jdk are used instead.

This probably won't work as I imagine XMLBeans returns a specialized DOM implementation that wraps there own objects to expose them through DOM APIs.

Comment: How do I get the value from a node without using the getTextContent method? The getNodeValue method picks up a null value!

Comment: @bot - You need to iterate over all the child nodes for the element that contains the text node.  Then for each child node that is of type text you need to get that nodes value and concatenate them together to get the String value.

Comment: So I need to iterate over text.getChildNodes and check if the child node is a text node and then get its value using the getNodeValue method instead of directly calling text.getNodeValue?

Comment: what method do I call to get the nodes value once I come across a node of type text since I can't use getTextContent or geyNodeValue?

Comment: @bot - I added a full example.

Comment: Thank you for spending time on typing out the code. I tried your approach but an empty string is picked up even though the tag contains a numeric value.

Comment: @bot - The code I posted works with the DOM implementation included with the JRE/JDK.  The XMLBeans DOM may not be acting correctly.

Comment: I would have accepted your answer but I am keeping this question open just in case someone knows how to get this done with XMLBeans and not just DOM alone. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well according to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxp/JAXP-Compatibility_160.html#dom), Java 6's XML support is supposed to be DOM 3 compliant.  See also the Java SE 6 [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).

This leads me to think that your application when you run it on JBoss must have older XML jars on the classpath, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: this is often caused by maven or something adding very old xml-apis or xmlParserApis  jars to the classpath, usually via xerces dependencies, these can be removed, Java has had XML built in for ages.  Modern Java code should never depend on xerces.