# DOM Level 3 Not implemented for XmlObject

Tags: java, dom, xquery, xmlbeans

I was trying to execute this:

```
XmlObject xmlobj = parseXml(filePath);
String testQuery = "$this//phone";
XmlObject[] x = xmlobj.execQuery(testQuery);
System.out.println(x[0].getDomNode.getTextContent());
```

Then it returns an error. How do I set DOM Level 3?

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: DOM Level 3 Not implemented

Comment: Did an error appear in the last line? You always need to check that element exist when you call it.

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace and the import statements. Ideally you should provide a minimal test example.

Answer (score 0):

You use [XmlObject](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.html), which is part of XMLBeans, which indeed does not implement DOM Level 3, so the exception you get is correct and you cannot use it this way.

If you are stuck to using `XMLBeans`, you can consider [the workaround proposed here by looping over the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12747130/111575), which is fairly straightforward to implement.